# Is there an efficient way to break a date range into hours per day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, datetime

In SQL Server I am attempting to break a date range into hours per day and have the following bit of code which is OK for a short time frame, but rather inefficient for longer periods of time.  Could anyone suggest a more efficient approach?

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2015-01-27 07:32:35.000',
        @EndDate   datetime = '2015-04-29 14:39:35.000',
        @TempDate datetime = '';

SET @TempDate = @StartDate;

DECLARE @dateTimeTable TABLE (dt datetime, minCol INT);

WHILE @TempDate < @EndDate
  BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @dateTimeTable VALUES (CONVERT(date,@TempDate), 1)
      SET @TempDate = DATEADD(minute,1,@TempDate)
  END

Select dt,
       FORMAT(SUM(minCol) / 60.0,'F') as Hours
from @dateTimeTable
GROUP BY dt
```

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: I don't understand the code you have currently: `minCol` is always `1` and `dt` always changes, so what's the point of grouping and summing? What actual end result are you trying to achieve: just a list of hours, or do you want to join to another table?

Comment: I was looking to get the number of hours or part hours for each day in a date range.  The answer given by eshirvana below gives me what I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use recursive cte :

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2015-01-27 07:32:35.000',
        @EndDate   datetime = '2015-04-29 14:39:35.000';

WITH cte AS ( 
SELECT CAST(@StartDate AS DATE) startdate,DATEDIFF(minute, @StartDate, DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(@StartDate AS DATE) ) ) / 60.0 hours 
UNION ALL 
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1, startdate), DATEDIFF(minute, DATEADD(DAY,1, startdate), CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY,2, startdate) > @EndDate
    THEN @enddate ELSE DATEADD(DAY,2, startdate) END) / 60.0
FROM cte 
WHERE startdate <> CAST(@EndDate AS DATE) 
)

SELECT * FROM cte
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=561e0ca45a6f07601e78f90fc035fcab)*

Comment: Wouldn't call it the *best*, Itzik's tally function will usually perform better, and doesn't require `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` which I note you haven't put in