# Break a date range into hours per day for each job

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

Yesterday I had asked for an efficient way to break a date range into hours per day and received an answer at the following link...
[Is there an efficient way to break a date range into hours per day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68257466/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-break-a-date-range-into-hours-per-day/68257968#68257968)

Now I need to go a step further and generate the same thing for each job in a list.  I have a table with the following sample information...

```
+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| JobID |        StartDate        |         EndDate         |
+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|     1 | 2015-01-27 07:32:35.000 | 2015-01-28 14:39:35.000 |
|     2 | 2015-01-27 07:32:35.000 | 2015-01-29 16:39:35.000 |
|     3 | 2015-03-02 09:46:25.000 | 2015-03-05 17:24:15.000 |
+-------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

And I need to get a list like the following...

```
+-------+------------+-------+
| JobID |    Date    | Hours |
+-------+------------+-------+
|     1 | 2015-01-27 | 16.47 |
|     1 | 2015-01-28 | 14.65 |
|     2 | 2015-01-27 | 16.47 |
|     2 | 2015-01-28 | 24.00 |
|     2 | 2015-01-29 | 16.65 |
|     3 | 2015-03-02 | 14.23 |
|     3 | 2015-03-03 | 24.00 |
|     3 | 2015-03-04 | 24.00 |
|     3 | 2015-03-05 | 17.40 |
+-------+------------+-------+
```

Can the recursive CTE (from the link I included) be modified to include a JobID?

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: Have you *tried* to make this modification?

Comment: Yes, but I was making it way too complicated and kept making a bunch of logic errors.  I added what I came up with below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with for a solution...

```
DECLARE @testTable TABLE (JobID INT, startdate DATETIME, enddate DATETIME);
INSERT INTO @testTable VALUES (1,'2015-01-27 07:32:35.000','2015-01-28 14:39:35.000');
INSERT INTO @testTable VALUES (2,'2015-01-27 07:32:35.000','2015-01-29 16:39:35.000');
INSERT INTO @testTable VALUES (3,'2015-03-02 09:46:25.000','2015-03-02 17:24:15.000');

WITH cte AS ( 
SELECT JobID,CAST(startdate AS DATE) startdate,DATEDIFF(minute, startdate, DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(startdate AS DATE) ) ) / 60.0 hours,enddate from @testTable
UNION ALL 
SELECT JobID,DATEADD(DAY,1, startdate), DATEDIFF(minute, DATEADD(DAY,1, startdate), CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY,2, startdate) > enddate
    THEN enddate ELSE DATEADD(DAY,2, startdate) END) / 60.0, enddate
FROM cte 
WHERE startdate <> CAST(enddate AS DATE) 
)

SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY JobID, startdate
```

Comment: @ScottHunter It did for me.